# Add Image Upload validation in SilverStripe CMS

Tags: php, silverstripe

How to add image upload validation in SilverStripe CMS?

I have to upload an image from a form with required validation in SilverStripe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **getCMSValidator** to set required fields in the CMS.

```
function getCMSValidator() {
    return new RequiredFields('Image');
}
```

Comment: Can you pls help me by providing other validation documentations in silverstripe. I'm new to silverstripe. Thanks.

Comment: RequiredFields http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-RequiredFields.html is about all you need in the cms. You can validate the UploadField by checking for file size, file extension. This page https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/ has some good examples